# Use Delegate in Model Layer to get a object available in later project/namespace

Tags: c#, entity-framework, delegates

My Model classes (Entity) are all generated in one project.  Is it possible for a property getter in that model to return class/object thats not available in that project but in a later one that uses that model.

```
Person
  Int Id
  String Name
  Object ImageInfo
```

Different Project Class that's not available to Model project/namespace

```
Imagecls
   WebClient myWebClient
   byte[] ImageByteArray
```

When I get the multiple records of the Person entity, I don't have security and other info needed for ImageCls in that project.  I want to access those records in a project higher up in the solution, but dont want to have to iterate through the set of Person records and add the class/object or create a new object that has both.

So want a Property that will do the Get at time of usage for displaying on screen so was thinking delegate would do this.

```
Object ImageInfo
  Get
   { return somedelegatemethod() }
```

Where I could change out the somedelegatemethod in the other project.  How do I do this or is there a better way?

Comment: You can probably do what you are thinking of.  However, it's hard to tell what you are talking about.  If you are discussing C#, you should show your thoughts in C# not some python-like pseudo code.  For example, I don't really know what you are talking about (at all) in your last code fragment (`Object ImageInfo` \n\t `Get` \n\t\t `{ return somedelegatemethod() }`

Comment: I'll repost question with better details.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70747262/use-delegate-in-model-layer-property-getter-available-in-different-project-names