# Use Delegate in Model Layer property getter available in different project/namespace

Tags: c#, entity-framework, delegates

My Model classes (Entity) are all generated in one project. Is it possible for a property getter in that model to return class/object thats not available in that project but in a later one that uses that model.

```
public partial class People
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastAccessDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public object MyImage { get; set; }
}
```

MyImage is not part of the actual Entity.  An extra property I want to get from.
In a different Project class I'm reading the entity as a list

```
 var mylist=db.People.ToList();
```

When I'm processing that list I want to then read MyImage on my view (MVVM).  But the MyImage is an object that doesn't exist in the Model level of the project.  It's where the views are.  How can I add a call to this MyImage getter to a class thats higher in the solution structure?

```
public class ImageHandler 
{
    public WebClient myWebClient { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageByteArray  { get; set; }
    public ImageHandler(int Id)
    {
        ..go process and get the image with security, etc...
    }
}
```

So I want to insert that class into the getter of MyImage after the records are retrieved and I have the info on the records that I need to call methods in the class.

```
    public object MyImage 
    {
        get
        {

            return somestaticcode.MyImage(Id);
        }
    }
```

The only way I could guess to do this is to put a static Delegate in the getter of MyImage that I change out in my current project before I display on the view the MyImage.  But I don't know how to do it, or if its the right way to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add properties in a referencing assembly, but you can add methods through C# [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), eg

```
static class PeopleExtensions
{
    public MyImage GetImage(this People p)
    {
        var ih = new ImageHandler(p.Id);
        return ih.GetImage();
    }
}
```